# Filtering out sections in nested object

Tags: json, filtering, jq

Given the following json:

```json
{
  "foo": {},
  "bar": {
    "a": {
      "tags": [
        "x",
        "y"
      ],
      "cycle": "simple"
    },
    "b": {
      "tags": [
        "x"
      ],
      "cycle": null
    }
  },
  "baz": {
    "c": {
      "tags": [
        "y"
      ],
      "cycle": null
    }
  },
  "qux": {
    "d": {
      "tags": [
        "x",
        "y",
        "z"
      ],
      "cycle": "complex"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to drop all objects in the top-level object which have `"cycle == null"`. When filtering for `"cycle"`, I don't know how to access fields from earlier filters:

```bash
$ jq '.[] | .[] | select(.cycle != null)' data.json
{
  "tags": [
    "x",
    "y"
  ],
  "cycle": "simple"
}
{
  "tags": [
    "x",
    "y",
    "z"
  ],
  "cycle": "complex"
}
```

I'd like to keep the structure of the matching entries, something like this:

```json
{
  "bar": {
    "a": {
      "tags": [
        "x",
        "y"
      ],
      "cycle": "simple"
    }
  },
  "qux": {
    "d": {
      "tags": [
        "x",
        "y",
        "z"
      ],
      "cycle": "complex"
    }
  }
}
```

I was hoping to write something like this `jq '.*.*. | select(.cycle != null)'` so that I wouldn't need to manually re-assemble the original structure, but didn't understand wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.[] |= …` (or `map_values(…)`) lets you manipulate the contents of objects without losing the outer structure. Nest it twice to go two levels deep. `select(.cycle != null)` is your main filter, but I've also added `select(. != {})` on the intermediate level as your desired output didn't include `"foo": {}`.

```bash
jq '.[] |= (.[] |= select(.cycle != null) | select(. != {}))'
```

```json
{
  "bar": {
    "a": {
      "tags": [
        "x",
        "y"
      ],
      "cycle": "simple"
    }
  },
  "qux": {
    "d": {
      "tags": [
        "x",
        "y",
        "z"
      ],
      "cycle": "complex"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FIqf5nhArdo)